# Would Henderson Alvarez have gotten credit for a "perfect" game if the score were still tied 0-0 after nine?

Tags: baseball

Henderson Alvarez of the Miami Marlins pitched a "perfect game" over the tops of nine innings. Going into the bottom of the ninth, the score was tied 0-0, but Miami scored a 1-0 walk-off with a wild pitch with two outs.

Would Alvarez have gotten credit for a "perfect game" if the Marlins hadn't scored? After all, he did pitch nine perfect innings.

Answer (score 5):

No.

Two reason this would not be a perfect game.

- First and foremost, he had allowed a walk, a batter also reached on an error. That means that he *only* qualifies for a No Hitter, and not a perfect game. A perfect game requires no one reach base.
- Second, a Perfecto requires that the pitcher retire every batter in the game. That means if the game goes 10 or longer, he must stay in the game in order to get credit for it being a perfect game.

As far as the no-hit bid, he would be eligible for credit on a no-hitter or combined no-hit bid in extra innings provided that he or a reliever continued to pitch no-hit ball. if a hit is allowed, even in extras the no-hitter is lost.

Comment: OK, if a starter pitches a no hitter for nine, he can still get credit after nine if he or the RELIEVERS maintain it until the final victory.

Comment: @TomAu he'd get credit for a combined NH, not a full one.

Comment: Fair enough. But at least people would know that he "did" nine. Thanks for your help in understanding.

Comment: A perfect game only requires the pitcher being the winning pitcher by virtue of the fact that he has to pitch the complete game, and a game cannot end in a tie.

Comment: @Joe that's what I get for using wikipedia for definitions. You are correct winning is *not required.* Games can in fact end in ties, though it is incredibly rare. The only case now is when weather interrupts an official tie game and there is no available reschedule date and there are no playoff implications

Comment: Poor Harvey Haddix.  He pitched 13 perfect innings before giving up a hit, and `Some years later, Milwaukee's Bob Buhl revealed that the Braves pitchers had been stealing signs from Pittsburgh catcher Smoky Burgess ... From their bullpen, Braves pitchers ... repositioned a towel to signal for a fastball or a breaking ball, the only two pitches Haddix used in the game. Despite this ... [13 perfect innings].   All but one Milwaukee hitter, Aaron, took the signals.` - Harvey Haddix, Wikipedia.  An amazing tribute to Haddix and Aaron

Comment: See http://www.nonohitters.com/near-no-hitters/ for games that went beyond 9 innings, including the classic [Pedro Martinez non-perfect-game in 1995](http://www.nytimes.com/1995/06/05/sports/baseball-paradise-lost-martinez-loses-perfect-game-in-the-10th.html), plus games where the pitcher performing the no hit lost in 8 1/2 innings (doesn't count), and rain shortened close calls.